# Installing PL/Java on OS X (Location of Java native libraries on OS X?)

Tags: macos, java

I’m trying to install Pl/Java on OS X, but I have some troubles. If the README calls for Unix systems to:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/client
```

What is the equivalent for OS X? I know I may need: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but what about the path in OS X?

Comment: Do you mean `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Libraries/`?
There are quite a few `.jnilib` files in there.

Comment: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `$JAVA_HOME` as so:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Then try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to $JAVA_HOME/bundle/Libraries or $JAVA_HOME/lib. Not a complete answer since I don't use PL/Java but hopefully this helps.